# Optimized Json Parsing

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing, foreach

I've been browsing thru the collection of question and answer at SO, but I can't find the right solution to my inquiry, though this question would not directly imply a programming answer, it will seek the appropriate approach which then can be converted into source code.. just in case the mods flag this question as not constructive.. anyway, that's just me...

I have an application that interfaces data from other databases by utilizing json, on my end I use PHP+MySQL, parsing the contents of the interfaced file, I would get an Array of Arrays of Arrays, please see below;

```
{
"p_head": [
    {
        "GROUP_ID": "700",
        "GROUP_DESC": "BBREAKFAST",
        "children": {
            "p_item": [
                {
                    "GROUP_ID": "200",
                    "PROD_ID": "113"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "GROUP_ID": "601",
        "GROUP_DESC": "AXPRESSO",
        "children": {
            "p_item": [
                {
                    "GROUP_ID": "200",
                    "PROD_ID": "113"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

Right now while parsing the said JSON data, I'm using 5 foreach loops,

```
1 to get the file contents,
1 to get the categories, store categories in array, store children in array
1 to expand the children array
1 to get to another level
1 to get to the array child
```

after that, I then again use foreach to loop thru the categories and start inserting them into the database, then another foreach loop to iterate thru the items and store each row into the database,

Here's a little question, is this solution just for readability's sake? Seems like I am coding as if I am a compiler, a line per line execution... In terms of efficiency? any drawbacks, waste of processing power? should I lessen the used of foreach, if so, how can it be implemented, below is the sample of the foreach looping...

```
foreach($json_array as $key=>$value)
{
//echo "The Value: " .$value;
$arr = $value;
//print_r($arr);
//Category Expanding
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    //echo "Key: ".$key."=>Value: ".$value."<br/>";
    //Category
    $category[] = array(
        'cat_prodcat_posid'=>$value['GROUP_ID'],
        'cat_description'=>$value['GROUP_DESC'],
        'cat_hierarchy'=>$value['POSITION_ID']
    );
    //Category Items
    $items[] = array(
        'item_grp'=>$value['GROUP_ID'],
        'item_arr'=>$value['children']
    );
    $categoryCount++;
}
//Items Expanding
foreach($items as $key=>$value)
{
    $v = $value['item_arr'];
    //print_r($v);
    foreach($v as $key=>$value)
    {
        $v2 = $value;
        //print_r($v2);
        foreach($v2 as $key=>$value)
        {
            //$v3 = $value;
            $item_expanded[] = array(
                'item_posid'=>$value['PROD_ID'],
                'item_poscode'=>$value['PROD_CODE'],
                'item_description'=>$value['PROD_DESC'],
                'item_prodcat_posid'=>$value['GROUP_ID'],
                'item_price'=>$value['PROD_PRICE']
            );
            $itemCount++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Is there anyway I could cut a shortcut specially on the items... I've used 3 foreach for that... or this solution is already at its best?

Answer (score 1):

When making you foreach loops, you can cut it down by going directly to the array you want to loop.

```
foreach ($json_array['p_head'] as $key => $val) {
    if ($key != 'children') {
        //do whatever with non-children
    } else {
        foreach ($key['p_item'] as $key2 => $val2) {
            //here is where your p_item info is
        }
    }
}
```

if my answer is the right answer, please mark it as such. Thanks